# JSP project does not run on Glassfish when clone from GitHub desktop or Gitbash

Tags: java, git, jsp, netbeans, glassfish

Recently, I have started working with a jsp application. The code repo is hosted on GitHub. I cloned the repository with gitbash for windows and later with github desktop application. When I open this project in netbeans and try to run, it gives me following error

> The module has not been deployed. See the server log for details.

The file where error is pointing to is

> F:\Git\KMATGit\KMAT\nbproject\build-impl.xml:1096

But when I clone the same project from netbeans. it works just fine without any problems. Any ideas what might be causing the problem

Comment: Compare line 1096 in build-impl.xml in a working project with one that is not working. This is a Netbeans specific build file. Maven as a build tool is more platform-agnostic and should avoid these quirks. It may be worth investing the time to learn.

Comment: As the message says: See the server log for details.